# Should I worry about password security?

Tags: java, security

My application displays an IP address and password on its GUI. The password changes periodically (for each new person that connects to it), and is only used once by the person connecting to ensure they're connecting to the right device. For example, two friends next to each other want to use my app, the one looks at the server's password to make sure they don't accidentally connect to another person using the app close by.

Users can also "pair" with another device, in which case they are asked for a password once, the server user is asked to confirm the pairing process and then no password is needed again. I do this by keeping a new randomly generated password and the other user's MAC address in a database.

Currently I use `String`s to store and compare the passwords everywhere in my app. I've read that using `char` arrays to store passwords is better for security because you don't have to worry about the intern pool keeping passwords in memory.

For my use case do I really need to worry about this kind of security? I'm not dealing with any user sensitive information, I just liked having a safety net.

Side question, how does one display a password kept in a `char` array on a Swing GUI without converting it to a `String` anyway?

Comment: To answer the side question: You Don't.  You either display a number of bullets, asterisks, or other dots to represent the password, or you don't display anything at all.  You should not display the actual contents of any security-sensitive anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, using a char array only gives you a false feeling of better security. If someone has physical access to your computer and its memory, using a String or a char array won't make a huge difference.

To answer the questions you asked though. The problem is not the pool of interned strings, because you won't intern your randomly generated strings. The problem is that the STrings are immutable, and thus kept in memory until garbage-collected without any (sane) way of resetting their content. All the elements of a char array can be reset to 0 after it's not needed anymore.

Regarding the way to display a password without transforming it to a String, you could simply paint each char on a JComponent directly for example. But if you're ready to display the password on a screen, thinking about the password staying somewhere hidden in the memory is quite contradictory to me.

Comment: "But if you're ready to display the password on a screen, thinking about the password staying somewhere hidden in the memory is quite contradictory to me." This is exactly what went through my mind.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of security is to avoid rights escalation. Basically each process has a certain set of things they are allowed to do, you need to ensure someone with access to one resource can't use it to gain access to another.

In your case, the main question is "What would a program gain by having access to the password?". If the main application already shows all pertinent information, would a rogue process (which has access to your memory space) have anything to gain by sniffing out the password?

If you were working with an online process, the answer could be yes. Getting a hold of someone's say Dropbox password has value, even if I already have extensive access to the local machine. However if you are talking about a local application, they likely would have little to gain by sniffing out the password.